# Pebble app installation failed

Tags: android, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I have created an application for my pebble, using CloudPebble and Simply.js.

Building from the Simply.js base app in Cloudpebble I have created my own one and installed on pebble succesfully.

Today I have changed some minor setting on project, and now installation (after successful build) always fails, showing the following massage:

**Installation failed with error code 1. Check your phone for details.**

After getting that message, I have installed other apps from cloudpebble, to rule out connectivity problems.

Someone has seen this error message?

BEst regards,

Enrique

Comment: Is your firmware up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Is your pebble in developer mode? Because I got the same error once and putting my pebble into developer mode made it work seeinf that it was my own app.

Comment: No worse answer than the rest... And **it is an answer**.

Comment: I had in developer mode. After some reboots it worked. Now I have changed to Pebble Time, but they do not have yet published and SDK for JS. Do anyone knows is there is a team working on it?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message after a successful build when all the slots on my pebble were full. Deleting an app from my pebble solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try and enter the ip address manually, you can do this by going into compilation in cloud pebble, and enter the ip address that is listed in the Pebble app on you phone.

This has happened to me before, hope it works, and good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I often have the same message.

I guess there are still some issues with cloudpebble...

Provided your project has so syntax or logical errors: just try to build/compile/install again, for me that works.